# What is 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 on Polygon

Tags: polygon

Can someone explain what is [0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000) on Polygon? It seems to be a smart contract and it can even send transactions.

Comment: Isn't that just considered a DEAD wallet?

Comment: I thought so too but apparently, it is not.

Comment: This is an interesting finding... veeeeery strange. It is some kind of a system contract... 

Comment: why do you say apparently not? Thats the burn address to destroy tokens

Comment: where do you see it send transactions?

Comment: If you click on the link you can see it. This is one example: https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x20460b4b05d03bfb6305ed9e081f5aafad42cb6939aeb9b416d59c46750327bd

Comment: If you open it you will see it: https://polygonscan.com/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: If you check address 0x0 on other chains, only on polygon it has a contract tab, and only on polygon there are SELF transactions, besides the regular IN transactions present on all chains... will dig further on this! 

Answer (score 0):

The 0x0 address does not have an owner. It can't be used or interacted with. You can olny send tokens there.
All values lying there can't be withdrawn out there. They are lost/burned.

Greetings ~Shadow